# locking types for MS Access 2010 INSERTS

Tags: .net, multithreading, ms-access, locking, ms-jet-ace

I have a simple multi-threaded .NET app which inserts rows into an MS Access 2010 DB using ACE.
It only does `INSERT` operations.
Because MS Access does page-level locking on inserts, I sometimes get locked out.

Is there a way to change this locking type?
Or is there a "danger mode" where I can tell it to ignore locks entirely and just potentially make new pages if it finds a locked one?

**EDIT:** Is there no way at all to control locking here? The hack I have which works thus far is by maintaining a single, shared connection for these transactions then the connection objects just queues up the inserts. This works but I don't like this connection just floating around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What interface are you using to updated the database? OLEDB? If so, this article seems to answer the question:

[PRB: Jet 4.0 Row-Level Locking Is Not Available with DAO 3.60](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306435)

It seems to be a matter of setting a property of the connection object:

> Set the Connection object's dynamic
>   Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Locking
>   Mode") to 1.

For what it's worth, I would not consider Jet/ACE to be a very suitable data store for this kind of thing, but it would depend on the frequency of the inserts.

10 an hour, no problem.

10 a minute, I'd switch to a different database.

BTW, using a single connection is the preferred method of working with a Jet/ACE data store because of the overhead of recreating the locking file each time you re-open the connection.

Comment: I will attempt this. That project is shelved for right now. It's really a debug helper, not production code, so there are a lot of shortcomings in the methods.